# Cannot modify the return value of dictionary because it is not a variable using struct

Tags: c#, dictionary, struct, variable-assignment

I'm getting the following compilation error: `cannot modify the return value of 'Dictionary<string, SessionLogDates>.this[string]' because it is not a variable`.

```
public static Dictionary<string, SessionLogDates> RegisteredTimes = new Dictionary<string, SessionLogDates>();
```

The added key-value pair look like this:

```
var tempDate = DateTime.Now;

RegisteredTimes.Add(requestUI, new SessionLogDates
{
    RequestStart = tempDate,
    LastProcess = tempDate
});
```

The `struct` declaration looks like this:

```
public struct SessionLogDates
{
    public DateTime RequestStart { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastProcess
    {
        get { return _lastProcess; }

        set
        {
            _lastProcess_cache = _lastProcess;
            _lastProcess = value;
        }
    }

    public bool LogCurrentProcess
    {
        get
        {
            var tempValue = _lastProcess_cache != _lastTimeLog;

            if (tempValue)
                _lastTimeLog = _lastProcess_cache;

            return tempValue;
        }
    }

    public bool InitialLog
    {
        get { return LastProcess == RequestStart; }
    }

    private DateTime _lastProcess { get; set; }

    private DateTime _lastProcess_cache { get; set; }

    private DateTime? _lastTimeLog { get; set; }
}
```

What can I do to re-assign it this way?

```
RegisteredTimes[requestUI].LastProcess = DateTime.Now;
```

Do I need to change to a `class` instead of a `struct`?

A detailed reason for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using a struct instead of a class? I dont see any rationale for using one. Additionally, you should provide a struct constructor (which requires full initialization of all struct fields) to ensure the DateTime structs are initialized as you expect.

Comment: Not a particular reason. I was just testing the struct's behavior to keep it in mind on future implementations.